# Batch file for getting all file names within a folder

Tags: batch, batch-file, irfanview

I'm using a program called Irfanview which can merge two images into one using its command line function. Here's an example:

`i_view32.exe /panorama=(1,C:\folder1\img1.png,C:\folder2\static_img.png) /convert=C:\marged_folder\img1.pdf`

How can I get all the image names from `folder1` and then perform this function for each one of them, taking into mind that the end result will be a PDF image with the same name `img1` but a different extension - PDF instead of PNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to dave_thompson_085, this will do without the double extension:

```
cd C:\folder1
for %i in (*.png) do i_view32.exe /panorama=(1,C:\folder1\%i,C:\folder2\static_img.png) /convert=C:\marged_folder\%~ni.pdf
```

Comment: `%~ni.pdf` will avoid 'doubling' the extensions.